# Does a Firebase observer in a table cell count as an observer for each instance?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I have a table with images in each cell, and I put the Firebase `.observer` in the custom tableview cell class, then does that count as having an observer running for each cell of the table?

So if 10 users post 10 cells each and there's 100 cells in the table does firebase basically see this as the same as having 100 observers?  Is this bad design?

After posting this I was thinking about how `UITableViews` work and it might be possible that the cells which aren't currently on the screen won't actually keep the observers running.  This would be really convenient and efficient if it works this way, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are correct in that the cells that are not on the screen don't actually "exist" yet.

Generally, you don't want to do anything intensive inside the cells themselves (API calls, rendering etc) because as you scroll, the tableview.dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier has to run through the code for every single cell that is being generated. You will experience a noticeable choppiness/lagg when scrolling (you might not notice it on a simulator because computers these days are pretty darn fast).

Answer (score 0):

1. Depending on your design, you might have one or more observers there. If you have by an instance of a class that calls Firebase's `observeEvent`, then yes, you will have a separate observers to Firebase's database, however that is still one connection to the database, as you are probably doing this through the main `FIRDatabase.database.reference()`.
2. Again, it dependes on how you implement the table view. You can have a look at [UITableViewCell documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/), especially at the part with reusable cells and `reuseIdentifier`. If you implement it that way, you will always have in memory only the (number of cells on screen + 1) cells allocated, which means the same number of observers.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "users": {
        1: {
            "username": "david"
        }
    },
    "posts": {
        1: {
            "text": "Hello World!"
        }
    }
    "user-posts": {
        1: {
            1: true
        }
    }
}
```

Given your database structure looks something like this, you would want to observe the `ChildAdded` event on the users path. For each child (user) you want to observe their user-posts e.g. `user-posts/1` would give you a list of post ids. Using these post ids, you can populate a table view cell per key and observe the full post e.g. `posts/1`. Bare in mind, once you've created the observer, unless you remove it, it will keep listening regardless of whether or not the cell is on screen. You can remove the observer when the cell did end being displayed using the corresponding Table View Delegate method.